# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

Does Mac OS X implement the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)?  If not, what's the equivalent of $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR?  An application I help maintain needs a temporary directory in which binary (i.e., executable) files can be placed and executed.  So this directory should be preferably unique to the user and must be guaranteed to allow files to have the executable bit set (if such a thing exists on the file systems used by Mac OS X).

Comment: Directories usually always have the executable bits... They cannot be listed otherwise...

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the directory should allow files *in* it to have the exec bit set.  In the *nix world many people mount their $TMPDIR as noexec as a security measure.  (I believe that the XDG Base Directory Specification vaguely prohibits this practice for $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, which states that that directory must be "fully-featured by the standards of the operating system", including "proper permissions".)

Answer (score 3):

Use `~/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems` on MacOS for the "runtime" directory; MacOS does not follow XDG.

A good reason for using something inside `~/Library/Caches` is that it's automatically excluded from Time Machine (the built-in backup and version control). So MacOS, and third party apps that follow MacOS conventions, will natively understand that anything in that directory is cache-like - which in particular excludes permanent application data, libraries/executables which are stable parts of the program, and config/etc.

The `TemporaryItems` subdirectory under caches has a history of being used for, well, temporary "working-memory"-style stuff - for example, Microsoft Outlook on MacOS used to use it for opened (and thus locally downloaded) attachments.

Similary, [the Python library `platformdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) seems to have made the same decision.

There's also `/private/var`... I don't know of any obvious reason to prefer that over `~/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems`. A tiny minority of users feel okay about randomly deleting `~/Library/Caches` - `/private/var` looks more system-y so maybe that gives it a bit more protection at the human vibes level. Also, a user's home directory might be network-mounted on MacOS servers/clusters, but there's no "standard" setup where `/private/var` is network-mounted. If those are enough of a concern for you, perhaps look into `/private/var/run` or `/private/var/folders`. I did a quick search and I wasn't able to immediately find any hint of how to correctly use `/private/var/folders` though... for example, how do you get your `/private/var/folders/??` subdirectory? But `/var/run` is the *original* (root/system) runtime dir, and `/private/var/run` is per-user, so it seems worth mentioning for completeness.

But as of this moment, I would use `~/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems`, since that seems to be the prevailing convention.

Comment: While it is true that MacOS does not follow XDG individual apps are free to do so. For example, the Elvish shell does so.

Comment: @KurtisRader In the case of the runtime directory, my answer *is* (the best approximation of) choosing to follow XDG on MacOS (or you can strictly follow the spec by acting as if there is no runtime directory in the absence of `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in the environment, since last I checked XDG does not specify a default value for the runtime directory like it does for many of the others, but since MacOS doesn't put that in the environment, that just means you either always fail, always use a fallback, or just push this question of what the runtime directory should be rootwards in the call tree).

Comment: @KurtisRader Also, individual apps might well be *wrong* in choosing to follow the XDG spec on MacOS (the same way that an app on an XDG system may be "wrong" to not do so), because the system, third-party apps, and the native/common user might all be directly or indirectly expecting, assuming, or even relying on the OS's conventions being followed. (If conventions are good to follow at all, then there is a very strong case to be made that the official/native/main convention on the OS you're running in is worth following. But yes, for some programs, following XDG on MacOS could make sense.)

Comment: I would at least put it into a sub directory called `runtime` to decrease potential collisions, although it won't be safe, but at least safer. Also `mkdir` and `chmod 0700` such dir to follow the guide lines from XDG.

Comment: On my macOS Ventura 13.6, `/var` is just a soft link to `/private/var`, so there's no distinction between system and per-user there. So `/var/run` technically violates the standard's requirement that it be owned by the user and 700. I'm going to go with it anyway, because that's where everything else seems to store those kinds of files. If I run into any trouble, I'll switch it to `/var/run/user/$USER`.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables):

> $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR defines the base directory relative to which
>   user-specific non-essential runtime files and other file objects (such
>   as sockets, named pipes, ...) should be stored. The directory MUST be
>   owned by the user, and he MUST be the only one having read and write
>   access to it. Its Unix access mode MUST be 0700.

There is not much other guidance given. I believe this to mean that you can put this in any folder in your `$HOME`. I posit that there's not much reason why this couldn't be the same as your `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` if the permissions are right and the data is cache-like.

Comment: Using "any folder in your `$HOME`" defeats the purpose of using specific, standardized locations such as those of the XDG Base Directory Specification.  (The idea is to prevent the filesystem from being littered with hundreds of different cache, config, and temp folders, each used by a different application.) The question is about whether the designers of Mac OS X (now macOS) explicitly specified a _particular_ location for temp executables, not whether it's safe to use one of your choosing.

Comment: Seeing as how it's not specified in the spec, it's apparently a free for all. Don't shoot the messenger. I don't like it either. I use `~/.run` personally.

Comment: For context, in most Linux systems, `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is `/run/user/$(id -u)`, where `/run` is a `tmpfs` (in-memory virtual file-system, which is a huge hint as to the intended purpose: your runtime dir is basically working memory or scratch space that just happens to be on the file system instead of in your process - it's not expected to survive between system restarts, user logins, and (although this is less obvious) even executions of your program).